# Laravel Non-Mutating Collection `put()` Method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

Does Laravel have a collection method that does the same thing as `->put()` but does not mutate the original collection?

What I'm looking for:

```php
<?php

$collection = collect(['key' => 'value']);

$new = $collection->putProperly('another', 'pair');

$collection // => ['key' => 'value']
$new // => ['key' => 'value', 'another' => 'pair']
```

I already know I can do this:

```php
$new = $collection->merge(['another' => 'pair'])
```

Comment: What does merge not do that you need? Merge returns a new collection, put modifies the original, but otherwise they seem the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method as seen in the list of available methods on the [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) but you can achieve the desired result easily by using the [clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword like this:

```
$new = (clone $collection)->put('another', 'pair');
```

Keep in mind that *clone* performs a shallow copy, therefore be careful if your collection contains objects which you also want to clone.